# My side project got accepted to a conference and my advisor is not involved in the project. How can I find travel funding?

Tags: conference, funding, travel

My side project got accepted to a conference and my advisor is not involved in the project. How can I find travel funding?

My advisor has kind of discouraged me from having side projects (but doesn't forbid me), and doesn't have a lot of money in general, so I would be afraid to ask him.

The main person I am working with on the side project is no longer at the university (he is now at a different university).

Comment: Also see [How would an undergrad fund a conference trip with a single author paper?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/60679/how-would-an-undergrad-fund-a-conference-trip-with-a-single-author-paper) and [Travel grants for International students in the US?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/897/travel-grants-for-international-students-in-the-us) for other sources of travel funding.